# Is the design of the Database efficient?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `app_ws_common` (                                                                                                     
          `serviceid` varchar(16) NOT NULL,                                                                                             
          `applicationid` varchar(16) default NULL,                                                                                     
          `modifieddate` date default NULL,                                                                                             
          `version` decimal(1,0) default NULL,                                                                                          
          `servicename` varchar(20) default NULL,                                                                                       
          `userid` varchar(128) NOT NULL,                                                                                             
          PRIMARY KEY  (`serviceid`,`userid`),                                                                                        
          KEY `table1_isv_fk` (`applicationid`,`userid`),                                                                             
          CONSTRAINT `table1_isv_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`applicationid`, `userid`) REFERENCES `applications` (`applicationid`, `userid`)  
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1



 CREATE TABLE `app_ws_user` (                                                                                                     
           `serviceid` varchar(16) NOT NULL,                                                                                              
           `userid` varchar(128) NOT NULL,                                                                                              
           `applicationid` varchar(16) default NULL,                                                                                      
           `modifieddate` date default NULL,                                                                                              
           `version` decimal(1,0) default NULL,                                                                                           
           `servicename` varchar(20) default NULL,                                                                                        
           PRIMARY KEY  (`serviceid`,`userid`),                                                                                         
           KEY `FK_app_ws_user` (`applicationid`,`userid`),                                                                             

           CONSTRAINT `FK_app_ws_user` FOREIGN KEY (`applicationid`, `userid`) REFERENCES `applications` (`applicationid`, `userid`)  
         ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `applications` (                  
            `applicationid` varchar(16) NOT NULL,        
            `userid` varchar(128) NOT NULL,            
            `applicationname` varchar(30) default NULL,  
            PRIMARY KEY  (`applicationid`,`userid`)    
          ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1  

 CREATE TABLE `external_ws_common` (           
               `serviceid` varchar(16) NOT NULL,        
               `modifieddate` date default NULL,        
               `version` decimal(1,0) default NULL,     
               `servicename` varchar(20) default NULL,  
               PRIMARY KEY  (`serviceid`)               
             ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1  


CREATE TABLE `external_ws_user` (            
                `serviceid` varchar(16) NOT NULL,          
                `userid` varchar(128) NOT NULL,          
                `applicationid` varchar(16) default NULL,  
                `modifieddate` date default NULL,          
                `version` decimal(1,0) default NULL,       
                `servicename` varchar(20) default NULL,    
                PRIMARY KEY  (`serviceid`,`userid`)      
              ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Here:

**app_ws_common** table contains all the application related services that are common to all users

**app_ws_user** table contains all the application related services created by a particular user and editted from its common version.

**applications** table will contain the list of applications and the corresponding user.

**external_ws_common** table will contain the list of services independent of all applications and common to all users.

**external_ws_user** table will contain the list of services that does not correspond to any application and created or edited from 'common' version of external service, by a user.

Now, I have to retrieve all application related services from table app_ws_user and all the services from table app_ws_common ,when they do not have the editted version for that particular user in app_ws_user table.

How can I write a query for this efficiently?
Or should I redesign this table ?

Comment: Not really related to your question, but I would advise you not to use `latin1` anymore. You might run into problems down the line. Use `UTF8` instead.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for the tip konsolenfreddy. :) So, what kind of problems will i face? Like,as I read, utf-8 supports multiple languages. So, if my charset is latin1 and if I want to store Japanese data, there comes the problem. Am I right?

Comment: yes, exactly. But also if you want to display the data on a UTF8 encoded website and have any kind of non-ascii characters.

Comment: please explain the use of application table

Comment: @SashiKant  Application table will have the list of applications based on which I can create a service.Also, every user will have access to his own applications and all common applications. But here we need to consider only the data in services table. I have added the Application table, as I have to show the Application Name in the filter result.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be help:::

```
SELECT 
      service_id, service_name
      FROM app_ws_common awc
    left join app_ws_user awu on (awc.serviceid=awu.serviceid and awc.applicationid=awu.applicationid)
UNION
    SELECT service_id, service_name
      FROM app_ws_common awc
    right join app_ws_user awu on (awc.serviceid=awu.serviceid and awc.applicationid=awu.applicationid)
```

Comment: Nope it does not work. My requirement is like say, app_ws_user has {1,'aa',1},{2,'aa',1} and the table app_ws_common has {1,'common',1},{3,'common',1}. The filtered list of all app services should be {1,'aa',1},{2,'aa',1} and {3,'common',1} where _{serviceid,userid,applicationid}_ ..

Comment: i have updated check this, and revert back if it still doesn't return the desired output

Comment: Thanks Sashi Kant :) The above query did not work. I was able form the required by correcting some logic.

Comment: SELECT awc.serviceid, awc.servicename,awc.userid,awc.applicationid
FROM app_ws_user awc
left join app_ws_common awu on (awc.serviceid=awu.serviceid and awc.applicationid=awu.applicationid)
where awc.userid= 'aa' and awc.applicationid = 1
UNION
SELECT awc.serviceid, awc.servicename,awc.userid,awc.applicationid
FROM app_ws_common awc
left join app_ws_user awu on (awc.serviceid=awu.serviceid and awc.applicationid=awu.applicationid)
where awu.serviceid is null and awc.applicationid = 1;

Comment: One more question.. While defining index, can we define index for UNION? Like an index on the fields we are going to do an union?